# Storing function in session variable

Tags: php

Is it possible to store an anonymous function in a session var and use it later on?

For instance:

```
$func = "echo $str;";
$_SESSION['myfunc'] = create_function('$str',$func);
```

When I call `$_SESSION['myfunc']('Hello')` it works fine on the page it is created in. When called in another page however, I get the error

> Call to undefined function()

The other session-vars are available, so that's not the problem. In the session data I see a reference to a lambda, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: can you specify your actual requirement of doing this ?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Why would you want to store a function in a session? Once you've refreshed the page, what do you get when you do a `var_dump($_SESSION['myfunc']);` ?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to convert user input into a function - which would be a very dangerous thing to do in most circumstances, so I advise caution if this is the case!

Comment: I don't know how you intend to use it. But it could open a door to **code injection**.

Comment: I was trying to pass a dynamically created function in stead of a whole bunch of variables, to make life easier. And no, it's not user generated variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store an actual function in a session variable - the variable that you're storing in the session needs to be serializable, and lambdas are not. Plus, this seems like a very convoluted thing to do.

Why not store the name of the function that you want to call, and then execute it that way? Or, if you really want to achieve this, you could store the function string in the session, then create the function after the session is restarted.

However, there's almost certainly a better way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is a library allowing to serialize closures: https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure

This might allow you to store a closure in a session.

Not sure it's a good idea, though.

Comment: Weird coincidence - I was just looking at the super_closure class over the weekend, even tweeted about it - but I haven't actually used it yet, so can't comment on how practical it is in a real-world environment

Answer (score 0):

The very reason that you would like to store a function in a session variable means that you're doing something wrong. What is the intention of this strategy from your side?